# Exclude unimported files from TypeScript typechecking

Tags: typescript

I have a huge TypeScript project (7600+ files, 2M+ lines of TypeScript) that I am trying to improve typechecking time for (currently at ~30 s in incremental mode).

The project contains lots of Relay-generated files for GraphQL queries and fragments in the `src/types/` folder. A number of those are not actually imported anywhere (e.g., refetch queries).

I would like TypeScript to skip typechecking for those, because they add up to a significant part of total check time (according to TS's `--generateTrace` output) and they're not going to have type errors.

How do I do this? I tried a few things:

- Add `src/types/` to `exclude` in tsconfig. But then TS complains (not unreasonably) that it can't find these files when they're imported.
- Add `src/types/` to `typeRoots`, which has the same problem.

Comment: you should exclude and include wisely. not only exclusion

Comment: Have you tried using distinct projects? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html  That should speed things up significantly when working on another project (at least, that was the theory behind it)